# DataTables: How to have wrapping texts and horizontal scroller bar together

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html-table, datatables-1.10

**Expected behavior**

I have a web page which contains a table with many columns. For every table cell, it may be short text or very long text. So I want to have a horizontal scroller bar for displaying well all type of text whether it is long or short.

**Environment**

Angular 5 (https://angular.io) and DataTables (https://datatables.net) which is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library for development.

**First Try**

I used horizontal scroller bar for displaying lot of columns. As the official documentation of DataTables mentions (https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html), I initialized my table with option `"scrollX": true;`, but I found the table didn't have the horizontal scroller bar. 
[image: The table has no change after setting <code>"scrollX": true;</code>]

**Second Try**

After setting option `"scrollX": true;`, I added `class="nowrap"` to my table, the horizontal scroller bar appeared, but the long text could not be displayed well.
[image: The table has horizontal scroller bar after setting <code>class="nowrap"</code>]

[**DEMO LINK**](https://118.190.151.166/manager/membermanager)
You can check it out by this web page , it has two tables whose option is `"scrollX": true;`, the upper has `class="nowrap"` and the lower doesn't.

**Question**

1. Why the table doesn't have horizontal scroller bar after setting option `"scrollX": true;`?
2. How can the width of columns change automatically according to the text's length after setting `class="nowrap"`?

Besides, any other solutions or ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `display: inline-block;` CSS to your table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added display: inline-block; but it was still the same display like the second photo in my question. The data was one line displayed.

Answer (score 0):

in datatable you can use responsive property no matter how long your data is it will manage responsively here you can see more

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/responsive.html

Comment: resize the page and see the effects

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually my problem is about table settings rather than responsive for different size of screen.